# Can we write to cache using serilog?

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, serilog

I'm trying to write logs in cache using serilog. Is it possible?

```
namespace MemoryCacheApplication.Controllers    
{    
    public class HomeController : Controller    
    {    
        private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;    
    
        public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)    
        {    
            this.memoryCache = memoryCache;    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: `write logs in cache using serilog` Can you clarify more about the actual scenario? So that we can understand your requirement better.

Answer (score 0):

> trying to write logs in cache using serilog

If it indeed requires writing logs in cache using Serilog under a specific scenario, to achieve it, you can try to implement a [custom LogEventSink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Developing-a-sink), like below.

```
public class MyMemoryCacheSink : ILogEventSink
{
    private IMemoryCache memoryCache;

    public MyMemoryCacheSink(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        memoryCache.Set("Clog", logEvent.MessageTemplate.Text);

        var log = memoryCache.Get<string>("Clog");
    }
}

public static class MyMemoryCacheSinkExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration MyMemoryCacheSink(
                this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        return loggerConfiguration.Sink(new MyMemoryCacheSink(memoryCache));
    }
}
```

*Use custom Sink*

```
private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;
public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
            
    this.memoryCache = memoryCache;

}

public IActionResult Index()
{

    var logger = new ReloadableLogger(cfg => cfg.WriteTo.MyMemoryCacheSink(memoryCache));
    logger.Information("hello world");
```

Test Result

[image]